# Internet access to LoPy (ESP32) using its GPIO pins

Tags: serial, esp8266, python, tcp-ip, lora

LoPy is a LoRa module which uses ESP32 chipset. It has WiFi and Bluetooth connectivity for Internet.

In my setup, I have certain interference issues, so I can't use WiFi nor Bluetooth to connect my LoPy to the internet.

Is their some way I can provide Internet to the module using GPIO pins? I am thinking of this setup:

- I will have a Raspberry Pi, which will be connected to the Internet either using USB tethering or LAN cable. This RPi will provide Internet to LoPy using serial communication through its GPIO pins.

However, I am not sure how I will achieve "providing internet access through serial port". How can this be done?

Comment: SLIP and PPP are traditional solutions for this, but there are also more limited bridges built that typical encapsulate an IP stack - for example the wiznet thing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for the lead. I will look into these options, and how to implement them on ESP32. If you know how to implement them on ESP, kindly add an answer.

Comment: If you can't use the radio features of an ESP, then why use an ESP at all? Use something that can run Python and has an Ethernet connection and stack. A RaspberryPi would be an obnvious choice.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: We already have ordered a bunch of LoPy modules. They are working fine everywhere, however in one location, interference is causing issues. Moreover, for LoRa, right now there aren't many options. As for RPi, it can't be used standalone; we will need a separate chipset for LoRa.

Comment: You didn't mention LoRa in the qustion :) I think it might be easier to send the data serially to the Pi and do the internet connection there, than to internet-over-serial.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Yes, that would indeed be the best option. However, we have a code running on LoPy, which directly communicates with our server software. We are re-workin that code to work on RPi. But meanwhile, I am also exploring the option suggested in the question.